# Delete node in linked list c++

Tags: c++

I think I am having an issue with the logic in my DeleteNode function in this linked list class. When I test the code it sometimes returns false when the node is in the list, and I haven't found a pattern.

If there is absolutely nothing wrong with this implementation of DeleteNode, the problem could be in the code where I am using the method, but if it is I want to take a look at that on my own before posting that code. (The purpose of me saying that is to let you know this code might be fine, but I want to know for sure).

Thanks so much!

Header file:

```
#include <string.h>
#ifndef LIST_H
#define LIST_H

class List {
public:
        typedef struct node {
                char * data;
                node * next;
        }* nodePtr;
        nodePtr curr;
        nodePtr temp;
        nodePtr head;
public:
        List();
        void AddNode(char * addData);
        bool DeleteNode(char * delData);
        bool containsNode(char * Data);
        void PrintList();
};

#endif
```

.cpp file:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "SLList.h"

using namespace std;

List::List() {
    head = NULL;
    curr = NULL;
    temp = NULL;
}

bool List::DeleteNode(char * delData) {
    nodePtr delPtr = NULL;
    temp = head;
    curr = head;

    while (curr != NULL && curr->data != delData) {
            temp = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
    }

    if (curr == NULL) {
            return false;
    }
    else {
            delPtr = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            temp->next = curr;
            delete delPtr;
            return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Does it delete properly if there is single node in the list?

Comment: What does this `char* deldata` represent? If it is text, you need to compare the text, not the pointer. However, in that case you should use `std::string` to begin with. Other than that, write a small program that only tests your list code in order to make sure that you catch errors, see also Test Driven Development.

Comment: Yes! Thank you! I forgot that I initially had the linked lists store integers, then changed it to strings. It works now :)